# How to remove excessive line spacing of downloadable fonts?

Tags: android, android-fonts

I am investigating downloadable fonts (and fonts as resources) within my current Android application.

When I place fonts within the `values/font` folder they display as desired.

When I employ downloadable fonts they always have additional spacing between the lines.

I have to use `android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.5"` within my layout xml to achieve the desired spacing.

I am applying the fonts to a textview and allowing it to wrap content.

I am concerned that using `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` may "clip" some characters.

What am I doing (or not doing) to create this text spacing issue?

Here's my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lexie_readable_regular"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/testing"
        android:textColor="@color/daynight_textColor"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/inknut_antiqua_light"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/testing"
        android:textColor="@color/daynight_textColor"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/tiresias_infofont"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/testing"
        android:textColor="@color/daynight_textColor"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/aphont_regular_q15c"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/testing"
        android:textColor="@color/daynight_textColor"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="CLICK ME"
        android:textColor="@color/daynight_textColor" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNightMode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:fontFamily="@font/tiresias_infofont"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="Night Mode"
            android:textColor="@color/daynight_textColor" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/switchCompat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:theme="@style/MySwitch" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The "downloadable" font is

```
android:fontFamily="@font/inknut_antiqua_light"
```

All the others are fonts I have manually placed in the `/font` folder.

And here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

This downloadable font looks OK

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
        app:fontProviderPackage="com.google.android.gms"
        app:fontProviderQuery="Actor"
        app:fontProviderCerts="@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
</font-family>
```

while this one has the issue shown above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
        app:fontProviderPackage="com.google.android.gms"
        app:fontProviderQuery="name=Inknut Antiqua"
        app:fontProviderCerts="@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
</font-family>
```

What is the difference?

I've tried using `android:includeFontPadding="false"`; it does not have the desired effect.

Comment: how does this question qualify for a downvote? From my testing this is a consistent issue with downlodable fonts, surely it needs to be addressesd

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot depicting the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably sinful of me but I was desperate to solve the line spacing issue, and adding a negative value to `lineSpacingExtra` seemed to work:

```
  android:lineSpacingExtra="-4sp"
```

For the "font padding" on the top and bottom of the TextView, you can use

```
  android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

I've tested on Android 5.1.1 & 7.0.

Fyi, I'm using **sp** because this is dealing with fonts.

Answer (score 0):

> **UPDATE:** Your font "inknut_antiqua_light" has the issue with large empty space. Other fonts are works without this issue. You can check the font space
>   below:

[image]

You can try removing font paddings by adding this line to your desired `TextView`

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fontFamily="@font/inknut_antiqua_light"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="@string/testing"
    android:textColor="@color/daynight_textColor"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />
```

Comment: employing android:includeFontPadding="false" made no difference to the issue

Comment: @Hector did you try any different downloadable font family? Have the same issue?

Comment: yes, every downloadable font I tried had the same issue

Comment: just tried with another downloadable font "ACTOR" and it does not have the issue. It must be associated with the font itself

Comment: @Hector I was about write the same answer, the font has the issue. Other fonts have no paddings. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use following attributes:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:letterSpacing="0.0"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"/>
```

Comment: android:letterSpacing is only available from 21 and above, my app needs to support from 19. In addition this doesn't resolve my issue